# Colon Operator with Deques (in Python)

Tags: python, arrays, slice, deque

I was hoping to use the colon operator with my deque but it didn't seem to work the same as a list.

I was trying something like:

```
myDeque = deque([0,1,2,3,4,5])
myDequeFunction(myDeque[3:])
```

This is the error I recieved:
"TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'"

What is the best way to do array slicing with deques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating is probably faster than brute-force methods (note: unproven) due to the nature of a deque.

```
>>> myDeque = collections.deque([0,1,2,3,4,5])
>>> list(itertools.islice(myDeque, 3, sys.maxint))
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You can supply `None` instead of `sys.maxint`

Comment: or `deque()` instead of `list()` if the OP wants a new `deque`.

Answer (score 2):

`deque` objects don't support slicing themselves, but you can make a new deque:

```
sliced_deque = deque(list(old_deque)[3:])
```

Comment: easy to understand, but `list(old_deque)` makes a copy of the entire deque so will be slow if deque is large

Answer (score 0):

`collections.deque` objects don't support slicing.  It'd be more straightforward to make a new one.

```
n_deque = deque(list(d)[3:])
```